# SMART: Raw Read Error Rate Errors on Mirrored Drives

Tags: hard-drive, smart, drive-failure

Thanks for reading.

I have a pair of 150GB WD Velociraptors that have failed SMART status.

The only fail they have is the Raw Read Error Rate, which is as follows.

.........Status:....Value:....Worst:....Threshold:....Raw Value:....Predicted TEC Date:

Drive 1: FAIL.......44........42........51............1485216.......N/A

Drive 2: FAIL.......24.......19.........51............1883052.......N/A

I'm not very familiar with SMART.  I assume this is a bad thing, and intend to replace the drives, but I do see a few people in forums saying the Raw Read Error Rate is BS and should be basically ignored.  Can anyone who is more familiar with SMART please give me a more informed opinion?

Also, will the fact that they're mirrored make any difference?  They don't have the same values, so I assume each is failing in it's own way, but will their mirrored status affect their SMART values in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: The mirroring status will not affect the smart values.  SMART is maintained by the drive, internally.  Any mirroring is done higher up the stack.

Comment: regarding the smart results themselves, I can't comment authoritatively but those numbers look pretty bad.  At the very least, make sure your backups are current.

Comment: @DanPritts - I just ended up replacing them.